# MonoTouch.Dialog change DialogViewController style

Tags: xamarin.ios, styles, monotouch.dialog, dialogviewcontroller

Is this possible to apply new style to already created `DialogViewController`? In one of my views I need to clear root and change from grouped to plain view.

Just setting style to new one doesn't do anything, so I'm not sure if I need to call some refresh method or this is not possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out looking at Monotouch.Dialog code that you need to call TableView.LoadView for this to happen.